# Trying to reverse posts from newer on top but I keep getting errors in Flask

Tags: python, flask

Here is the code I'm trying to run in my Flask App

```
    {% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Testing title{% endblock %}


    {% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Posts</h1>
    <h3>Postings</h3>
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <input hidden placeholder="Name" name="name">
            <input placeholder="Post whatever you want..." name="post" required>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        {% for post in posts reversed %}
        <div>
            {{ 'Anonymous' + ': ' + post[2] }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

This is the error I get jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'reversed'

Figure reversed would work since I found some examples online that does that

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: so there is a list of posts but at the very top of the list are just old posts everytime I submit a new post it's always at the bottom, I'm trying to make it where the new post goes on top instead of the bottom

Comment: Could you please post your python code. @DjKniteX

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax in Jinja2 to loop through a list in reverse order is:

```
{% for post in posts|reverse %}
    {{ post }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hey thanks! This works great! It's one step at a time for me.